# Why should I use Kafka connect mongo DB source connector over change streams only?

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, scalability

I need to consume changes coming from changes in MongoDB.
As I explored my options, I noticed that there are two common options to do so:

1. Consume the MongoDB change streams directly
2. Use the MongoDB Kafka source connector to publish the messages to the Kafka topic and then consume this topic.

I'm dealing with a high throughput so scalability is important.

What is the right option and why? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "consume directly"? Using Debezium you mean? Or are you asking about not using Kafka at all? If so, then that obviously introduces a point-to-point dependency to the database , and Kafka can act as a decoupled temporal buffer

Comment: No. I mean consuming the mongo change stream from Kafka by a connector (Debezium is one option), or consuming the change streams with the Mongo change stream API https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/

Comment: There's no difference? Both are consuming the change stream. One is just a level of abstraction done through Kafka. So question becomes - do you want to write "change stream reading code" using Kafka consumer or some API that Mongo provides? What if you needed multiple services to read that data? Does re-playability matter?